# AngularJS v1.3.5 - Page reloads twice on route change after npm install

Tags: angularjs, routes, npm-install, single-page-application, bower

I am facing an issue with AngularJS version 1.3.5 in my project. After performing an npm install with recent changes, I noticed that whenever there is a route change on my AngularJS page, the page reloads twice instead of once as expected. This issue was introduced suddenly after the new build and I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

Expected Behaviour
After a route change in the AngularJS application, the page should not reload since it is single page application.

Actual Behaviour
The page reloads twice on every route change, causing unexpected behavior and affecting the user experience. The page reloads on every route change, causing unexpected behaviour and affecting the user experience.